# Blog not showing without adding www on domain?

Tags: html, redirect, blogger, blogs

I have a blog at http://www.futuristiccreativity.tk but if I type it without `www` on the browser, i.e., http://futuristiccreativity.tk it shows up error loading the blog.

Is there any possible solution for this redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is one of the most common problems of bloggers who use blogger for publishing their content and set up a blog. I too suffer from this the most.

Recently, I made a way out of this problem. Though Google support tells to add A records which point to these IPs to redirect to the `www` version of the site, that doesn't work for me:

- 216.293.32.21
- 216.293.34.21
- 216.293.36.21
- 216.293.38.21

But a simple way out is, remove all these A records and have just one record.
Now the solution, Go to your domain registrar dashboard and add an A record whose host is `@` and points to `174.129.25.170` IP. And all your problem will be gone within some time(it may take up to 24hrs for DNS to migrate the preferences)

Check out [my blog post](http://www.genicsblog.com/2019/08/how-to-easily-redirect-to-www-version-of-site.html) to have a better understanding.